# when I click in some box-color , the code I write in JavaScript should return his value in locale-storage but it return just the first Color I select

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, local-storage

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgGdY.png)

[css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQzrU.png)

[JavaScript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFSC.png)

[code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfniR.png)

Comment: Please don't post text as images. Post text as text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is **random  tag in line 9 of you HTML file**.
2. Localstorage is not propery updating real time data in developer tools.
   I removed the div tag and added **console.log(window.localStorage)** each time click-listener fires.[line 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6nOS.png)

```js
let list = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
let myBox = document.querySelector(".box");

list.forEach((li) => {
  li.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    list.forEach((li) => {
      li.classList.remove("active");
    });
    e.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
    window.localStorage.setItem("color", e.currentTarget.dataset.color);
    console.log(window.localStorage);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}  
ul {
  background-color: rgb(207, 204, 204);
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  list-style:  none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
ul li[data-color = "red"] { background-color: red; }
ul li[data-color = "green"] { background-color: rgb(26,131,5); }
ul li[data-color = "blue"] { background-color: rgb(22,8,221) }
ul li[data-color = "black"] { background-color: rgb(20,16,16); }
.box {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
  <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="active" data-color = "red"></li>
    <li data-color = "blue"></li>
    <li data-color = "green"></li>
    <li data-color = "black"></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```